# Modify ffmpeg batch file to replace extension instead of appending new one

Tags: batch, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a bunch of .flv's in a folder to .mp3's with FFMPEG in Windows XP.

This batch file works fine for me.

```
for %%A IN (*.flv) DO ffmpeg -i "%%A" -ar 44100 -ab 128000 -ac 2 "%%A.mp3"
```

BUT it passes the old flv extension to the mp3, eg song.flv to song.flv.mp3
I know I could fix this double extension problem with this:

```
FOR %%f IN (*.flv.mp3) DO RENAME "%%f" "%%~nf"
```

So I'm sure I'm missing something simple like putting %~n1 somewhere. Just not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused. You obviously know about **%%~nf**, so why don't you similarly use **%%~nA.mp3**?

(This *is* the answer BTW; it's not just a comment.)

P.S. Use `for /?` to learn more about what **~n** means.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks. I see that my other for code is wrong too. It only removed the .mp3, not the .flv part. Working on that now too.